# Unable to launch app on real device - Xcode shows Memory corruption

Tags: xcode

Unable to find the root cause for the below issue.

App is not launching after adding custom frameworks to the existing app. Xcode logs shows below error and trigger is reaching till main.swift and crashed

**objc[425]: Memory corruption in class list.**

Comment: Hi Shamshuddin Shaik, Can you please mention which custom framework are you using.

Comment: It has happend when i try to add EmiratesID toolkit framework provided by ICA, UAE. I see no issue from Framework side.